# В чём разница между методами replaceAll, replaceFirst, replace и matches?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Объясните разницу в методах и почему matches выдаёт false

Код:

```
public class Reg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String temp = "практ.зан. а. 4-спорт зал";

        System.out.println(temp.replaceAll("а[\\.+][\\S\\s][0-9-, цехспортзал]+", ""));
        System.out.println(temp.replaceFirst("а[\\.+][\\S\\s][0-9-, цехспортзал]+", ""));
        System.out.println(temp.replace("а[\\.+][\\S\\s][0-9-, цехспортзал]+", ""));
        System.out.println(temp.matches("а[\\.+][\\S\\s][0-9-, цехспортзал]+"));
    }
}
```

Ответ:

```
практ.зан. 
практ.зан. 
практ.зан. а. 4-спорт зал
false
```

Comment: [Изучайте][1].

  [1]: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: @fortuna58rus, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

Метод `matches()` проверяет, соответствует ли строка регулярному выражению *полностью*. Чтобы проверить, есть ли подстрока, соответствующая регулярному выражени, используйте `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(temp).find()`.

Метод `replaceAll` заменяет все вхождения регулярного выражения. Метод `replaceFirst` заменяет первое вхождение. Метод `replace` заменяет все вхождения, но не регулярного выражения, а литерала (его первый параметр интерпретируется как конкретная строка для поиска).

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, методы, вызываемые у темп, явно указывают на разницу, переведите replace All, replace First, matches на русский.